# Remove or ignore empty cells in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

I have tried every solution / code I've seen here and nothing worked. Didn't change anything. 
I have a loop where I define my arrays. Some cells are merged where I'm copying from and the array includes the empty columns as well.

This is my code:

```
var array = []; 
  for (var m = 0; m < startRows.length; m++) { 
    array[m] = sourceSheet.getRange(startRows[m],5,3,29).getValues().filter(String); 
  }
 // Logger.log("array:   " + array[0]);
```

Why is this not working?

Edit:
Log of array[0]:

```
[20-01-14 14:54:29:668 GMT] array:   Chlorine content,,,,,1 / d,,ASTM D5463,,,,,NSP601,,,Sat Dec 30 1899 14:05:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time),,0.42,,,,ppm,,,0.3 - 0.5,,,,,TREATED SEAWATER,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: How is the array looking like ? Can you provide an example of the array ?

Comment: Is `String` a function or a variable? It needs to be [a function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp).

Comment: @ADW it's a function, I've seen that solution here before, however, it doesn't change anything, still shows the empty cells.

Comment: The best practices in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/ discourage the use of Google Apps Script methods calls in loops, by the other hand, please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use a loop to get the values from a Range. 
You can do the same with:

`var array = sourceSheet.getRange(startrow,5,3,29).getValues();`

or if you are getting all the values of the Sheet:

`var array = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues()`

However, you can remove empty spots of an array with the [splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) function. Since it's removing positions, the array will shrink every time it finds an empty spot, so the `for` loop used here has to go backwards:

```
  for (var i = array.length; i >= 0; i--){

    if (array[i] == ''){
      array.splice(i, 1); //i is the index, 1 is the number of positions to delete
    }

  }
  Logger.log(array);
```

In case you declare and set the values for the `array` without the loop, it would be a 2D array, as you can see in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [
  "Chlorine content",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "1 / d",
  "",
  "ASTM D5463",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "NSP601",
  "",
  "",
  "Sat Dec 30 1899 14:05:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)",
  "",
  "0.42",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "ppm",
  "",
  "",
  "0.3 - 0.5",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "TREATED SEAWATER",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  ""
];
const result = arr.filter(el => el);
console.log(result)
```

If this is your array, that means that you can filter the empty values using a simple filter, instead of `.filter(String)`

Comment: Arrow functions aren't supported by default in Google Apps Script.